# Searching git diff output for specific kinds of changes

Tags: git, shell, ksh

I am writing a Korn Shell script, where I am trying to iterate over specific lines in the `git diff` result of a file. For those who don't know, `git diff` lists the changes made to a file, and its output would look something like this (assuming only lines 3 and 5 changed):

```
unchanged line 1
unchanged line 2
- previous version of line 3
+ new version of line 3 
unchanged line 4
- previous version of line 5
+ new version of line 5
```

I have stored this result in a string variable (say, `diff`), and I need to iterate over each line in `diff` beginning with a `+` or a `-` (for instance, `- previous version of line 3`). The most intuitive solution is obviously to iterate over each line in `diff` and use something like `if line contains + or -`, but I can't do this since `diff` is not an array of separate lines, but a string separated by `\n` at places.

So what I end up looking for is a way to extract each part of the string between two `\n` characters.

How do I achieve this in Korn shell? Or maybe you guys could suggest better alternatives.

Comment: And you've failed to tag `korn` in this.. Btw, a doubt. Doesn't korn shell support bash like arrays?

Comment: @sjsam korn doesn't show up as a tag when I search for it. It was showing up until yesterday. And korn does support arrays. Are you suggesting I extract each part of the result between two `\n` characters and move it to an array?

Comment: I don't think you need to extract it. You can always do a command substitution inside an array operator. Regarding the korn tag, sorry about that then

Comment: added Korn shell tag, please tag appropriately

Comment: @yacc korn isn't showing up as a tag today when I search for it. In fact, ksh wasn't showing either for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below approach should fit

```
git diff | grep '^[+-]' |  while read -r -d$'\n' line
do 
if [ ! -z "$line" ] 
# The last line would always be empty, but cond. above is an overkill anyway
then
 # Do something useful with "$line"
fi    
done
```

Since you need lines starting with either `+` or `-` I have added a `grep` too to filter lines.

---

<sup>**Note:** used  `ksh 93u+ 2012-08-01` emulator found [[ **here** ]](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_ksh_online.php)</sup>

Comment: `diff=( $(git diff) )` seems to have made each part of the git diff result separated by any white space character into a separate element of the array. So currently `unchanged`, `line` and `1` are all separate elements of the array. I'm hoping to have each line as a separate element of the array.

Comment: @lebowski : Indeed I noticed that and that is not what you wanted. So see the edit..

Comment: @lebowski You're welcome. I have added  `grep` too to filter the results.. See the final edit.